# Using PHP wants to export html into doc,excel

Tags: html, excel, iframe, export, doc

File is exporting properly, but HTML file contains iframe , So iframe part is not exported in doc and excel. iframe calls html file for graph. Graph is done using flex.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please rephrase your question, I have absolutely no idea what you mean. What are you exporting from where to where using what?

Comment: I have a feeling that Manisha is writing an HTML file with an extension of .doc or .xls, and believing that this is now a MS Word or MS Excel file

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) and [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) Libraries. These are PHP libraries that will enable you to create real MS Excel and/or MS Word files.

Comment: @Pekka, Thanks for reply.
we are creating surveys using PHP, CI and Users can give response to their surveys. 
we want report of all responses.
we have displayed all responses on one page and also shown a graph of responses.
Graph is created using flex. and it is shown in iframe. for e.g (<iframe src="graph.html?id=100"></iframe>)
We are downloading response in doc and in excel file using downloadfileclass.inc. 
All responses on the page is properly downloaded in doc file except the graph. This is the problem. How we can get the content in iframe into a doc file?

Comment: How are you actually creating the doc/xls files? Is the graph actually created by flex rather than server-side PHP code?

Comment: Yes the graph created by flex. and to display the graph used iframe. and whole content is just written to doc file. Code is as below                                                        $myFile = "./reports/doc_report.doc";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $content;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);

fclose($fh);
include("./embed/downloadfileclass.inc");

$downloadfile = new DOWNLOADFILE($myFile);

if (!$downloadfile->df_download()) {
 echo "Sorry, this file is not currently available for downloading.";
}

Comment: You're not really creating a doc or an xls file. What you're doing is just writing your html to a file with an extension of .doc. If you have to do that, rather than creating a real doc file, can your flex application generate the image as an actual file that can be saved to disk? Or can the iframe be replaced with a div?